# Cruise Control .NET web dashboard not loading CSS properly

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol, agile-processes

I am having trouble figuring out why my cruise control .net web dashboard is showing up all screwed up(see image). It seems like it can't load all the style sheets properly.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of IIS you are using?

For Windows 7, there is a IIS7 feature that you need to enable before images and css is working on websites:
Turn on "Static Content" located under "Common HTTP Features".

Comment: Thanks Alina! I am running Windows Server 2008R2 and Static Content happens to be disabled under Web Server Role by default.